# Mi elemento no se actualiza

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Tengo un "panelGroup" con un render que depende de una variable boolean, y un botón que cambia el estado de ese booleano pero al momento de darle click al botón, el panelgroup no se actualiza hasta que recargue la página a pesar de que SÍ tengo un update.

xhtml:

```
<h:form >
    <p:commandButton class="btn" value="mostrar foo"
        action="#{developerController.foo}" update="foo"/>

    <h:panelGroup id="foo" rendered="#{developerController.bar}">
        foo
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Mi bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named(value = "developerController")
@SessionScoped
public class DeveloperController implements Serializable {

private boolean bar;


public DeveloperController() {

}

public void foo() {
    bar=!bar;
}

public boolean isBar() {
    return bar;
}

public void setBar(boolean bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
}
}
```

¿Qué debo hacer para que se actualice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como Lithorel indica, el rendered=false tiene la culpa de no actualizarse.
Dicho esto, otras opciones además de la que él propone:

**Opción 1:**

```
update="@form"
```

El handicap es que se actualiza todo el form.

**Opción 2:**

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton class="btn" value="mostrar foo"
        action="#{developerController.foo}" update="miPanel"/>

    <p:outputPanel id="miPanel">
        <h:panelGroup id="foo" rendered="#{developerController.bar}">
            foo
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```

El elemento miPanel se pinta siempre y por lo tanto puedes actualizarlo.

La opción del CSS también es buena, es cuestión de gustos.

Comment: El outputPanel fue la mejor opción pues dentro de mi panelgroup tenía dos formas y al meterlo dentro de otra forma daba error, excelente.

Answer (score 2):

El renderer hace que tu panelGroup no vaya en el html por lo que el update no sirve ya que el elemento id=foo no existe.

Una solucion es usar display:none / display:block en el style y hacer la seleccion con el condicional del bean.

```
<h:form >
    <p:commandButton class="btn" value="mostrar foo"
        action="#{developerController.foo}" update="foo"/>

    <h:panelGroup id="foo" style="#{developerController.bar ? 'display:block;' : 'display:none'}">
        foo
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Comment: "El renderer hace que tu panelGroup no vaya en el html". Error. Esto hace que el componente no se cree en el UITreeView, por ende no puede ser re renderizado. En este caso, lo que haces es que el componente esté en el árbol de la vista y, por ende, renderice su HTML, luego controlas la lógica de visible/oculto.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando se desea actualizar el atributo `rendered` de un elemento, el `update` se debe realizar al elemento padre:

```
<h:form id="frmFoo">
    <p:commandButton class="btn" value="mostrar foo"
        action="#{developerController.foo}" update="frmFoo"/>

    <h:panelGroup id="foo" rendered="#{developerController.bar}">
        foo
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Con el `rendered` en `false`, el elemento no existe, por eso no lo encuentra al hacer el `update`.

Answer (score 1):

Muy buenas opciones las ya mencionadas, supongo que lo que estás desarrollando va más allá de un simple foo.

También puedes usar **styleClass** para realizar **update** y asignarlo solo a los elementos que quieras actualizar para evitar utilizar tantos contenedores y referencias más largas; cuando tu código crezca considerablemente podrás ver la practicidad de ésta técnica.

Fíjate en el siguiente ejemplo cómo solo actualizamos un elemento, sin importar qué tan anidado se encuentre.

```
<h:form >

    <p:commandButton class="btn" value="Calcular Neto" action="#{beanController.calcular}" 
      update="@(.neto)"/>

    <h:panelGroup id="contenedorPrincipal" >


         <h:panelGroup....

               <h:panelGroup......

                    <h:outputText value="Neto: "/>
                    <h:outputText styleClass="neto" value="#{bean.neto}" />

               </h:panelGroup>

          </h:panelGroup>

    </h:panelGroup>

</h:form>
```

Aquí puedes encontrar una guía con ésta y otras técnicas que te harán más fácil localizar tus componentes:

https://youtu.be/hooHODgu6aM

Saludos!